# Determine How much of the GPU's processing power an asset is using when rendered

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics

I'm looking to profile how much of the GPU's power an individual asset is taking up by being rendered. It doesn't have to be super accurate, just kind of a rough estimation.  Is there anyway to access the performance information of a graphics card?  I was hoping there might be some kind of Windows API, but have yet to turn up anything.  I would just use Unity's Profiler, but they don't expose any of that information in their c# script.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you didn't even mention, what platform?

Comment: It might be applicable to use the Unity Profiler, and render a scene containing a very large number of just that asset.

Comment: Using Direct X and I mentioned that I'm developing it for Windows @JoeBlow
HalpPlz Its not applicable as the Unity Profiler provides inaccurate information.  The idea is to display the information In app on a per asset basis so we can profile it on device with out having to divine information from the over stuffed profiler.